# Why won't the Server Explorer properly enumerate or add servers, and access WMI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have this problem with the server explorer in Visual Studio 2010, and I have tried reinstalling, repairing, etcetera, but nothing has worked. If I right click and add a new server, it cannot connect by either name, IP, or other. I really need access to SE.

[alt text http://img808.imageshack.us/img808/61/serverexplorerissue.jpg](http://img808.imageshack.us/img808/61/serverexplorerissue.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server explorer come to find out is sensitive about the name of your computer. Apparently a name like '0x01' will not work in the SE.